# Protecting routes with authentication in an AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

Some of my AngularJS routes are to pages which require the user to be authenticated with my API. In those cases, I'd like the user to be redirected to the login page so they can authenticate. For example, if a guest accesses `/account/settings`, they should be redirected to the login form.

From brainstorming I came up with listening for the `$locationChangeStart` event and if it's a location which requires authentication then redirect the user to the login form. I can do that simple enough in my applications `run()` event:

```
.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
        // Decide if this location required an authenticated user and redirect appropriately
    });
}]);
```

The next step is keeping a list of all my applications routes that require authentication, so I tried adding them as parameters to my `$routeProvider`:

```
$routeProvider.when('/account/settings', {templateUrl: '/partials/account/settings.html', controller: 'AccountSettingCtrl', requiresAuthentication: true});
```

But I don't see any way to get the `requiresAuthentication` key from within the `$locationChangeStart` event.

Am I overthinking this? I tried to find a way for Angular to do this natively but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I use [angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) in my project. If you have a backend is easier to delegate on it to handle the authentication, showing a login form automatically in each 401 response, than duplicate the authentication mapping both on client and server.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is implement an angularjs interceptor which handles http request errors. Basically, what I do is when I get the 401 (unauthorized) from my backend, I save the current url  and redirect the user to a login page. When the user does login successfully, I retrieve the saved url to set the path with $location.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

    /* Global interceptor for 401 - not authorized */
    var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', 'authorizationService', function ($location, $q, authorizationService) {

        function success(response) {
            return response;
        }

        function error(response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                authorizationService.saveUrl($location.path());
                $location.path('/logon');
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
            else {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        }

        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(success, error);
        };
    } ];
});
```

In the logon controller (on successful logon) I set the location like this:

```
$location.path(authorizationService.getUrl());
```

Comment: This seems like my best solution so far, however has the drawback that my application will have to wait for a 401 response from the API before it knows to redirect to the login page. On my application's account settings page, there is no API call being made until the user saves their settings, meaning they'll get the account settings screen when they're not logged in.

Comment: You can always set the login url in the app.run() section with  $location.path('/logon'), which is being run when the application starts.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I only show the login page for certain routes while checking if the user is actually logged in or not?

Comment: You could check the path with $location.path() and act accordingly.